# Unable to read excel file , list index out of range error, cant find Sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlrd

I am trying to read excel (.xlsx) file and convert it to dataframe. I used pandas.ExelFile , pandas.read_excel, openpyxl load_workbook and even io file reading methods but i am unable to read Sheet of this file. Every time i get list index out of range error or no sheet names is case of openpyxl. Also tried xlrd method.

```
temp_df = pd.read_excel("v2s.xlsx",  sheet_name = 0)
```

or

```
temp_df = pd.read_excel("v2s.xlsx",  sheet_name = "Sheet1")
```

or
`from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook(filename="v2s.xlsx",read_only = True, data_only = True)
workbook.sheetnames`

[Link to excel file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/122JnmlpaSZa0cp7FLZ2btCSdPQoSMRus/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: try `xl = pd.ExcelFile('v2s.xlsx')` then `print(xl.sheet_names)` check to see if that sheet exists, the error looks like it doesn't exist.

Comment: xl = pd.ExcelFile("v2s.xlsx")
print(xl.sheet_names)  this returns [] an empty array

Comment: That answers your question the excel file is empty

Comment: @Datanovice the excel file is not empty, there is a sheet with data on it.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this ticket](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/956/userwarning-error-when-load_workbook-a), the file is saved in a "slightly defective" format.

The user posted that he used `Save As` to change the type of document back to a normal Excel spreadsheet file.

Your file **is** this type:

[image: Save as type]

You need to save it as:

[image: New type]

Then running your code

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook(filename="v2s_0.xlsx",read_only = True, data_only = True)
print(workbook.sheetnames)
```

**Outputs:**

```
['Sheet1']
```