# pandas.read_excel() cannot read an .xls file, what is going wrong?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, xls, xlrd

I am using pandas 2.2.0 and xlrd version is 2.0.1. The code snippet

```
import pandas as pd
filepath = './data/myfile.xls'
df = pd.read_excel(filepath)
```

generates the following log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/singhd/PycharmProjects/Debugging/main.py", line 30, in <module>
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/singhd/PycharmProjects/Debugging/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 495, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(
         ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/singhd/PycharmProjects/Debugging/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 1567, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/singhd/PycharmProjects/Debugging/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlrd.py", line 46, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/singhd/PycharmProjects/Debugging/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 573, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(self.handles.handle, engine_kwargs)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/singhd/PycharmProjects/Debugging/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlrd.py", line 63, in load_workbook
    return open_workbook(file_contents=data, **engine_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/singhd/PycharmProjects/Debugging/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 172, in open_workbook
    bk = open_workbook_xls(
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/singhd/PycharmProjects/Debugging/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 68, in open_workbook_xls
    bk.biff2_8_load(
  File "/home/singhd/PycharmProjects/Debugging/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 637, in biff2_8_load
    cd = compdoc.CompDoc(self.filestr, logfile=self.logfile,
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/singhd/PycharmProjects/Debugging/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/xlrd/compdoc.py", line 227, in __init__
    dbytes = self._get_stream(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/singhd/PycharmProjects/Debugging/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/xlrd/compdoc.py", line 293, in _get_stream
    if self.seen[s]:
       ~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: array index out of range
```

It reads the file when I open it in Excel and save it as .xlsx, so the .xls file does not seem to be corrupt. What is going wrong here? What else can I try? Is this a well-known issue?

Comment: Not sure if this answer can help out in getting to start discarding possible issues:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60142739/14550654

Comment: @AlbertoJLorenzoRosario My post is about .xls format, which is not supported by openpyxl anymore. Converting it with Openoffice/Excel works but I was intending to use the source file as it is. Thanks for your comment anyway.

Comment: Clearly its XLRD that has a problem with your XLS file so drop Pandas part for now and just work with XLRD. I don't work with XLS files so not very familiar with XLRD and wont pretend to know what the code is doing exactly in `self._get_stream`. It seems maybe related to the directory but could be way off. It seems your XLS file is XLS and not another format masquerading as XLS (so it's still read by Excel) since would expect XLRD to return a different error. XLRD does have some verbosity logging options for loading a file, see the docs, but can't guarantee it will tell you anything useful.